# Exception does not catche in child thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have Test class which opens infinite reading loop in its constructor using class ReadingLoopThread(Thread) and then it has to be able to execute some other functions (such as while_loop_function function). I need to catch KeyboardInterrupt in this infinite loop **inside the child thread**, but all I have is an error:

```
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1294, in _shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1060, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1076, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My code:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class ReadingLoopThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, ):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print('a')
                sleep(0.5)
            except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                print('in loop: interrupt')
                raise(e)

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_thread = ReadingLoopThread()
        self.my_thread.start()

    def while_loop_function(self, msg):
        print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        test = Test()
        test.while_loop_function('blablabla')
    except Exception as e:
        print('in main')
        print(e)
```

Comment: Exceptions are not passed to other threads.

Comment: And how could I solve that problem?

Comment: See the duplicate post.

Comment: The string "blablabla" has not been printed, it seems that main thread waits for child to be exited, which is not appropriate for me. I need child to execute in parallel way.